# Perl - don't send double sql request

Tags: sql, perl, request

i have a perl script and i don't want to send a double request :

the request is '2018-03-15 12:30:00', 'Metric A', 62 and i want send only one time and not more :

in my mariadb bdd i have double line :

```
 SELECT time, measurement, valueOne FROM `metric_values`;
```

results :

```
+---------------------+-----------------+----------+ 
| time                | measurement     | valueOne |
+---------------------+-----------------+----------+ 
| 2018-03-15 12:30:00 | Metric A        |       62 | 
| 2018-03-15 12:30:00 | Metric A        |       62 |
```

my perl scipt :

```
use DBI;
open (FILE, 'logfile');
while (<FILE>) {

($word1, $word2, $word3, $word4, $word5, $word6, $word7, $word8, $word9, $word10, $word11, $word12, $word13, $word14) = split(" ");

$word13 =~ s/[^\d.]//g;


    if ($word13 > 5) {

        if ($word2 eq "Jan") {

        $word2 = "01"
        }

        if ($word2 eq "Feb") {

        $word2 = "02"
        }

        if ($word2 eq "Mar") {

        $word2 = "03"
        }

        if ($word2 eq "Apr") {

        $word2 = "04"
        }

        if ($word2 eq "May") {

        $word2 = "05"
        }

        if ($word2 eq "Jun") {

        $word2 = "06"
        }

        if ($word2 eq "Jul") {

        $word2 = "07"
        }

        if ($word2 eq "Aug") {

        $word2 = "08"
        }

        if ($word2 eq "Sep") {

        $word2 = "09"
        }

        if ($word2 eq "Oct") {

        $word2 = "10"
        }

        if ($word2 eq "Nov") {

        $word2 = "11"
        }

        if ($word2 eq "Dec") {

        $word2 = "12"
        }

        print "'$word5-$word2-$word3 $word4', $word11, $word13 \n";

              }
    # Connect to the database.
    my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=db;host=ip",
                           "titi", 'mp!',
                           {'RaiseError' => 1}) ;


    my $sth = $dbh->prepare(

        "INSERT `metric_values` (time, measurement, valueOne) VALUES('$word5-$word2-$word3 $word4', $word11, $word13);")#result is ('2018-03-15 12:30:00', 'Metric A', 62)

        or die "prepare statement failed: $dbh->errstr()";
    $sth->execute() or die "execution failed: $dbh->errstr()";
    print $sth->rows . " rows found.\n";

    $sth->finish;
```

my log file:

```
Wed Oct 17 04:57:08 2018 : Resource = 'toto' cstep= 'titi' time =23.634s 
Wed Oct 17 04:57:50 2018 : Resource = 'toto' cstep= 'titi' time =22.355s
```

## thanks for your response

Comment: Your script does only a single insert. If you call it multiple times it will do multiple inserts. Am I correct that you are actually looking for a way to not insert a row if it is already there? In this case [How to INSERT If Row Does Not Exist (UPSERT) in MySQL](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/) might help.

Comment: i execute this script every 5 minute and that create many same line in the table, i don't want same line in my table

Comment: Create a unique index on the fields that should be unique?

Comment: @jack: I'm not sure what you problem really is. This script uses a fixed statement to insert a line - which will of course add the data when executed since these data are hard coded in the script. If you intention is to have only this single row in the table then why do you execute this script multiple times?

Comment: i show you all code

Comment: i do all request of my logfile

Comment: I've edited your question to fix the formatting of the input file. You're welcome, but please consider doing it yourself in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment, you say this:

> i execute this script every 5 minute and that create many same line in the table, i don't want same line in my table

I think this is what is happening.

Every five minutes you run your program. Each time you run the program you use exactly the same log file as input. So the same records get processed every time and new copies of the data are inserted on each run.

There's nothing wrong with your existing code. It's doing exactly what you've asked it to do. It's just not clever enough. You need to make it cleverer. You have a few options.

1. Remove from the log file the records that have been processed. That way you only insert each record once.
2. Add a flag to each record in your log file which indicates that it has been added to the database. You can then check that flag when processing the file and only insert records that don't have the flag.
3. Add an index to your table to ensure that it can only contain one copy of each record. You'll then need to change your code so it ignores any duplicate data errors that you get back from the database.
4. Use [`REPLACE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replace/) instead of `INSERT` and ensure you have the correct primary key on your table to ensure that duplicate records aren't inserted.

Without knowing a log more about your particular application, it's hard to know which of these options is the best approach for you. I suspect you'll find the `REPLACE` option the easiest to implement.

**Update:** I hope you'll find some general comments on your code to be useful.

Your code to open the file works, of course, but it is some distance from current best practice. I recommend a) using a lexical filehandle, b) using the three-arg version of `open()` and c) checking the return value from the call.

```
open my $fh, '<', 'logfile'
  or die "Could not open 'logfile': $!\n";
```

Using variables called `$word1`, `$word2`, etc is a terrible idea. A better idea would be to use an array:

```
my @words = split ' ',
```

If you really want individual variables, then please give them better names:

```
my ($day, $mon, $date, $time, $year, ... ) = split(' ');
```

Personally, I'd turn each record into a hash.

```
my @cols = qw[day mon date time year ... ];

# and then, in your loop
my %record;
@record{@cols} = split ' ';
```

Converting the month to a number the way you do it is clunky. Consider setting up a conversion hash.

```
my %months = (
  Jan => 1,
  Feb => 2,
  ...
);
```

Then your code becomes (assuming `$mon` instead of `$word2`):

```
$mon = sprintf '%02d', $months{$mon}
  or die "$mon is not a valid month\n";
```

But, actually, you should use something like [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) to deal with dates and times.

```
my $timestamp = "$day $mon $date $time $year";
my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime($timestamp, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S $Y');
say $tp->ymd, ' ', $tp->hms;
```

Comment: Adding a "processed" flag in a (text) log file is likely to involve re-writing the entire file every time (although there are ways around that). The better way to avoid re-processing log lines would be to use File::Tail (https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Tail) or similar so that each new run can pick up where the previous one left off instead of starting from the beginning of the file every time.

Comment: @DaveSherohman: I didn't claim they were all **good** options :-)